"Lens" kind of behaviour without using any lens
The title might seem absurd but recently I noticed a very strange thing with a straw.
For your reference I have a myopic vision and use a correcting lens of power -4.5D.

So one day while reading a book without my specs, I kept my book at a distance where texts got blurred up completely.  Then I hold a straw close to my eye (as in the first figure) and thought to see through it but as obvious everything was still blurred. But the interesting thing happened when I pinched the end close to my eye. When I saw through that pinched end I could actually read the texts well enough which was very strange for me. I don't know how but by making the aperture small the straw is behaving like a lens of some sort (which shouldn't really happen as its only air throughout the straw so there is no other media to focus the light beam).
So can someone explain how exactly is this happening ?

Before pinching :-

After pinching :-


You're basically squinting, but using an external eyelid. Already answered here: https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/1039/pinhole-camera-how-how-to-see-without-your-glasses-works

This is amazing. I couldn't find this post. Thanks for pointing it out.

You should read up on Pinhole glasses while you read that other post.
